# I am getting question marks on serial while trying to read SD card

Tags: avr, spi, sd

I am using SPI and I'm trying to initialize and read a SDHC card. In the terminal, all I get back are question marks scrolling across the screen. Normally, I would think this is a baud rate issue but I have tried different baud rates and verified the the baud in the code matches the baud rate of the modem. My question is why am I getting question marks "?" in place of alphanumeric characters as expected. The question was answered and resolved. The issue was due to the terminal not interpreting HEX because the setting was set to interpret ASCII. I changed the terminal settings to HEX and all is good.

Comment: Have you tried displaying hexadecimal values?

Comment: I the values of the "data-stream" characters do not correspond to any "printable" character, some terminals print a placeholder char like '?'. You should use a terminal that supports hexadecimal display of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your terminal is set to only display the standard set of ascii characters from decimal 32 through to decimal 127: -

[image]

And, if a character outside this range comes along, a question mark (ascii 63d) replaces it. A simple reason could be that every byte recieved has its MSB set.

You need to find a way of showing all characters like this: -

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's it. I changed my terminal to HEX and now its spitting out numbers. Now I need to find a good SDHC / FAT32 library to read and write to the card. Thank you

Comment: Great, glad it was a simple fix.